# How do I make a drop shadow with a halftone effect?

Tags: font-identification, effects, drop-shadow, halftone

[image]

I have already tried doing with Drop Shadow settings and i could only produce a black smudged shadow, not the spotted one. Look at this text. Can you see that spotted shadow behind the text? I want to know how to do that.

Is it related with brushes? Or something in the drop shadow? Or maybe something else? Please Help Me.

Also, does someone know the font name?

Comment: You might want to google 'halftone drop shadow', with 'Photoshop' and 'tutorial' thrown in.

Answer (score 11):

Start with a normal `Drop Shadow`. Play a little with the settings (Don’t forget to use `Spread`).
[image]

Right-click the Effect Layer and select `Create Layer` (Ignore any warning dialogue).

[image]

Merge the new Drop Shadow layer with your white background (Or create a Smart Object from them). If you like you can tweak the shadow a little bit with `Curves` or `Levels` to make the core of the shadow darker.

Now Select Filter > Pixelate > Color Halftone. The first input box controls the size of the dots. Fill the rest of them with the same value to get a b/w halftone effect instead of a colored one.

[image]

If you worked with Smart Objects, you can now still change the settings a little bit to get a better result.

[image]